# Reducing the size of the a-frame canvas to show other HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, aframe

If this is possible, can I change the size of the aframe canvas in code?

I would like to display a form so that users can modify object parameters in the aframe scene.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: The docs are currently out of date. You can try using an iframe or adding the `embedded` component to your scene. I've filed an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1949) to determine the recommended approach, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question. [How to remove fullscreen styles in A-Frame, reduce canvas size, or scroll a page with A-Frame scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754553/how-to-remove-fullscreen-styles-in-a-frame-reduce-canvas-size-or-scroll-a-page)

You can use the `embedded` component to remove fullscreen styles and make it embeddable within a web page. https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/embedded.html

```
<a-scene embedded> 
  <!-- scene stuff -->
</a-scene>
```

Then you are free the style `<a-scene>` how you wish

```
a-scene { display: block; width: 50%; }
```